# Getting "error loading operating system" when I start a VM. Worked fine prior opening with VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vmware-workstation

I'm using VMware Workstation 7.x on Windows and I'm getting this error when I start my VM:

```
error loading operating system
```

That started to happen when I tried to load the VMDK file into the program VirtualBox. Prior to this, it ran just fine. Ever since then I have been unable to start it in VMware Workstation 7.x

I've already tried to repair the VMDK file but when I do it tells me there are "no errors found". I used

```
vmware-vdiskmanager.exe -R "c:\blah\my vm disk.vmdk"
```

Anyone else have any more suggestions I could try? It's a 300+ GB VM and I don't want to lose it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the VMWare converter?  If so it should give you two options:

1. Choose the volume and then create the vmdk
2. Maintain the Disk Size.

I believe you want the second options.

Comment: But i already made the VM and just decided to try and see if it would work in VirtualBox. It only messed up because i try to start the VM in VirtualBox and VirtualBox did something to the vmdk file i guess?

Comment: Where is this WMWare converter?? I downloaded the stand-alone one from the website and it never gave me any of those 2 options you said to look for above?

Comment: Did you take any snapshots of the guest?

Comment: @fergNab: no i did not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Read this for background re migration and differences: http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows

Most likely, you'll be able to get it running again with a Windows Rescue disk.

Either create your own: http://www.ehow.com/how_5046115_create-windows-xp-rescue-disk.html

or find one here: http://www.freepctech.com/index.php/downloads/336-boot-disks

I downloaded an zipped ISO from the above link and mounted it using VirtualBox to the cd rom and booted from that. I was back in my windows machine in no time.